# Randomly position divs upon page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, positioning

I want a set of divs to position randomly upon page load. The divs are currently set to move around the viewport in a random fashion, but all seem to load in the top left corner.

The method I currently have:
(https://jsfiddle.net/j2PAb/634/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    animateDiv($('.a'));
    animateDiv($('.b'));
    animateDiv($('.c'));});

function makeNewPosition($container) {

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $container.height() - 50;
var w = $container.width() - 50;

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

return [nh, nw];}


function animateDiv($target) {
var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
var oldq = $target.offset();
var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

$target.animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
}, speed, function() {
    animateDiv($target);
});

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

var speedModifier = .1;

var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

return speed;}
```

Comment: These are `fixed` positioned elements and you have not defined their initial position in `css` hence their default position will be `(0,0)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I could set different start positions via top, left, bottom, right, however, I want the divs to start at a completely random position upon page load. I changed the positioning to absolute in css without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the random values to the top and left of these divs before you animate them.

Like below...

```
function randomstart($target) {
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    $target.css({top:  newq[0], left: newq[1]});

};
```

Check the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/j2PAb/636/).

Comment: Perfect Ryan, thanks! Another random question, but would you happen to know how to create a pacman styled effect on these divs, in which loop off the edge and reappear on the other side?

Comment: I think you should check steps function of jquery animate for this feature. You need to check the top and left of the div and if they exceed the viewport position, move it to the opposite site. Check the step function in the following link. 

http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step

Answer (score 1):

just define their initial `top` and `left` positions like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/j2PAb/635/)

```
div.a {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
 background-color:red;
position:fixed;
    top: 300px;
    left:10px;
}
div.b {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
 background-color:blue;
position:fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left:50px;
}
div.c {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
 background-color:green;
position:fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left:200px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an initialization method to set the position of each div.

Something like:

```
function initDiv(target) {
  var newq = makeNewPosition(target.parent());
  target.css({top:  newq[0], left: newq[1]});
  animateDiv(target.show());
}
```

Also do hide the divs initially, so the movement is not noticed by the user:

```
div.a, div.b, div.c {
  display: none;
}
```

So the Updated code looks like ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2PAb/637/)) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  initDiv($('.a'));
  initDiv($('.b'));
  initDiv($('.c'));


});

function initDiv(target) {
  var newq = makeNewPosition(target.parent());
  target.css({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  });
  animateDiv(target.show());
}

function makeNewPosition($container) {

  // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
  var h = $container.height() - 50;
  var w = $container.width() - 50;

  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

  return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv($target) {
  var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
  var oldq = $target.offset();
  var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

  $target.animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, speed, function() {
    animateDiv($target);
  });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

  var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
  var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

  var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

  var speedModifier = .1;

  var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

  return speed;

}
```

```css
div#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
div.a,
div.b,
div.c {
  display: none;
}
div.a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
div.b {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
}
div.c {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class='a'></div>
  <div class='b'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
</div>
```